# Netty performs slow for huge payload on POST request

Tags: json, post, java-8, netty, payload

I am using netty-4.0.32.Final. following are my channel configurations.

```
EventLoopGroup elGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            bootstrap.group(elGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 15000)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.MAX_MESSAGES_PER_READ, Integer.MAX_VALUE).option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
                            p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                            p.addLast(new HttpRequestHandler(router, monitor, fileWriter,kafkaWriter, pluginManager,redisConnectionPool));
                        }

                    });
```

Even We tried with EpollServerSocketChannel with EpollEventLoopGroup, but we get the below result in AB for huge payload POST request.

2858byte - post.json

Requests per second:    **3452.96** [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       72.402 [ms] (mean)

However, when we reduce the payload data in the request, the result is below.

277byte - post3.json

Requests per second:    **10085.06** [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       24.789 [ms] (mean)

However, when we make GET request, we get the below result.

Requests per second:    **22592.77** [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       11.065 [ms] (mean)

Can anyone guide me how can we improve the performance for the huge payload POST request.

P.S: max of our request will have huge payload.

Answer (score 0):

There are some information maybe help you :

1. Use a `bossGroup` and a `workerGroup` maybe work better(See the example from netty website).
2. AB (Apache benchmark tool) should be turn on keepalive option(Reuse TCP connection, it's very important, may be a lot of time waste on bulid TCP connection ans release them, use `netstat -naplt|grep yourport` may be see some).
3. I found you some configure is big (like buffer), it's not the bottleneck.

I have been test Netty HTTP(just a simple test, small data) performance, it can be near reach 200000 request per seconds(Multi client and asynchronous via apache HttpAsyncClient and use PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager to keep reuse TCP connections).

Finally, view Netty examples is a good idea.